# Yongnuo RF-603 II: difference between N1 and N3 versions

Tags: nikon, triggers, yongnuo

I now have Nikon D7000 and Sb-600, 800 and 900. To trigger all this equipment I used CLS which works unreliable under some circumstances. And I looked at the radio triggers for that purpose.

I trusted Yongnuo equipment and I stuck to YN RF603 version ii (as it has better ergonomics).

However the eBay suppliers specified additional N1 or N3 names. Not without some difficulties I found out that

- **N1** is for Nikon N90s F5 F6 F100 F90 F90X D1 D1H D1X D2 D3 D3s D2H D2X D2Xs D100 D200 D300 D300s D4 D800 D800E D700 with MB-D100 D200 D300, Kodak DSC-14N, Fuji S3 Pro Fuji S5 Pro and
- **N3** is for Nikon D90 D3100 D7000 D5000 D3200.

Actually I was a bit surprised that it can be any difference. Besides some sellers mixed them [in one package](http://www.ebay.com/itm/4x-Yongnuo-RF-603-II-N1-N3-Wireless-Flash-Trigger-3-Receivers-for-Nikon-DSLR-/331162268742?pt=Camera_Flash_Accessories&hash=item4d1acf3446): "*Note : You will get 1pcs YONGNUO RF-603II N1 and 1pcs RF-603II N3, total is 2 sets and 4pcs transceivers, so you can use them compatible with all Nikon Cameras*".

I'm really will be able to use only two of them if I'd buy this pack? If I'd buy D700 in a future I will not be able to use the ones I used on D7000?

It's a bit out of my understanding :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between the two packages you're looking at is the shutter release cable that's included in the package--the radio triggers themselves are identical units.  But since Nikon uses two different shutter release connectors depending on whether the camera is entry-level or prosumer, there are two separate shutter release cables, for when you use the triggers for remote shutter release, rather than flash triggering.

It's the same on the Canon side of the fence: all the Canon versions of the triggers are identical; it's just the shutter release cable that differs between the C1 and C3 packages.

*However* the Canon and Nikon versions are *not* identical.  The contacts of the hotshoe on the top are the same, but the triggers use brand-specific pin configurations on the foot.

Comment: Thanks! So I do not need to worry? I can take tha pack I specified?

Comment: If you don't care about using the 603ii for shutter release, yes. Personally, I'd say go with a N3-specific listing, and look for a dealer with a good reputation and return policy, like thephotogadget.com, a 'fulfilled by Amazon' Amazon listing, or Yongnuo themselves on ebay (hkyongnuophotoequipment).